# Why can't use the newly installed TensorFlow library using python 3?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I recently upgraded to python 3.5 and was trying to use TensorFlow. I followed the instructions https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html and installed tensorflow with GPU enabled:

```
# Mac OS X, GPU enabled, Python 3.4 or 3.5:
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/gpu/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-py3-none-any.whl
```

however, when I tried using tensorflow it threw a really strange error:

```
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/user/path/venv2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/Users/user/path/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Users/user/path/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/user/path/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Users/user/path/venv/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Users/user/path/venv/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user/path/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.7.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/user/path/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
  Reason: image not found
```

why is it throwing that error? I know that I do not have a GPU but I was under the impression from other conversation on the TensorFlow page that I don't require one to use the version that can potentially use a GPU.

Comment: `Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.7.5.dylib` Have you installed CUDA?

Comment: Where did you get this impression from? Sounds... wrong. You can force the gpu version to construct nodes that only run on CPUs, but as far as I'm aware you'll still need a CUDA installation, and for that I'd assume you need an nvidia GPU.

Comment: @DomJack https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3632 it says there that: `TensorFlow has separate builds for CPU and GPU binaries (http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/) You seem to be running a GPU build on a machine that has no GPUs, hence the warning. However, it should still work regardless, this message is purely informational.` from the developers of TF.

Comment: You learn something new every day...

Answer (score 0):

you need to export the path to the folder of the cuda dylibs (like libcudart) with `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your `~/.bash_profile`